# How to create Read More and Read Less in using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some text data store in my database, And I am displaying to my view page, But I want to show read more and read less functionality on my view page, Because content is more then 700+ words, When I am clicking on read more it's automatically hiding all the content. Let me guide where I am doing mistake.

Here are my view file:

```
<span class="more">
    {!! ($prop->description) !!}
</span>
```

Here are my CSS code:

```
<style>
  .morecontent span {
    display: none;
  }

  .morelink {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
```

Here are my jQuery Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Configure/customize these variables.
    var showChar = 100; // How many characters are shown by default
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Show more >";
    var lesstext = "Show less";


    $('.more').each(function() {
      var content = $(this).html();

      if (content.length > showChar) {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
      }

    });

    $(".morelink").click(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
      } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
      }
      $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
      $(this).prev().toggle();
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Bhavik, Please Check the given code...

Answer (score 0):

Do it simply like this....

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxLength = 300;
    $(".show-read-more").each(function(){
        var myStr = $(this).text();
        if($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength){
            var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
            var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
            $(this).empty().html(newStr);
            $(this).append(' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more">read more...</a>');
            $(this).append('<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + '</span>');
        }
    });
    $(".read-more").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".more-text").contents().unwrap();
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

```css
.show-read-more .more-text{
        display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p class="show-read-more">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working correctly, just keep same structure in your view file.

If your content is contain html tag then you should use [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)
like `{{htmlentities($prop->description}})`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Configure/customize these variables.
  var showChar = 10; // How many characters are shown by default
  var ellipsestext = "...";
  var moretext = "Show more >";
  var lesstext = "Show less";


  $('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if (content.length > showChar) {

      var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
      var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

      var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

      $(this).html(html);
    }

  });

  $(".morelink").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
      $(this).removeClass("less");
      $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("less");
      $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.morecontent span {
  display: none;
}

.morelink {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="more">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </span>

<span class="more">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </span>
        
<span class="more">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </span>
        
<span class="more">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </span>
```

Comment: Hi Omi, It's working fine with this code  `{{$prop->description}}` but data is displaying on html format, adn if I am using  `{!! $prop->description !!}` this functionality is not working.

Comment: can you please post snapshot in OP

Comment: Hello Omi, Please open this link `https://prnt.sc/qchfrg` and check the error.

Comment: I have updated answer. But problem is since it is containing html tag, it also count that characters also

Comment: This code `htmlentities($prop->description` is Working Fine, but getting some extra tags `https://prnt.sc/qchwgj`, Please cehck screenshot

Comment: I solve this issue using `{{strip_tags($prop->description)}}` this tag.

Comment: ok sounds good that is also fine, but there will be no 100 characters exactly you have do some more code to take .text() only instead of .html()